# Identify mac or local ip address

Tags: macos, ip, ip-address, local, router

I have a list of mac addresses and local ip addresses from my router. 
In order to use the right ip address I need to identify which device is behind each ip address.
So my question is how can I know which device is linked to each address? Is there a way for me to find this out from my computer only?

Thanks,

Siar

Comment: Unless you have DNS entries for all the IPs, no.

Comment: You can try `arp -a` and there is an app for iPhone/iPad and others called `fing` that may help.

Comment: I found an software called Advanced Ip scanner, it did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain some information by portscanning.

```
sudo nmap -O $IP_ADDRESS
```

will return some information about the OS, you can possibly use this to identify which device is which?